# Insert html form data into the end of a table <tr> using vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, html-table

I created a javascript function that fires onSubmit and is supposed to take the input data and add it into a new row of a table on the same page.

I am not seeing any errors in my console. But the data is not making it to the table.

Below is my first try:

```
    function addRow() {
      // Get a reference to the table
      let tableRef = document.getElementById('Job-table');
       console.log(tableRef);
      // Insert a row at the end of the table
      let newRow = tableRef.insertRow(-1);

      // Insert a cell in the row at index 0
      let newCellJobName = newRow.insertCell(0);
      let newCellJobDate = newRow.insertCell(1);
      let newCellJobHost = newRow.insertCell(2);

      // Below I is a test with a static string
      //let newJobName = document.createTextNode("TEST 1");
      //let newJobDate = document.createTextNode("TEST 2");
      //let newJobHost = document.createTextNode("TEST 3");

  // Append a text node to the cell
  let newJobName = document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("JobName").value);
  let newJobDate = document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("JobDate").value);
  let newJobHost = document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("JobHost").value);

      newCellJobName.appendChild(newJobName);
      newCellJobDate.appendChild(newJobDate);
      newCellJobHost.appendChild(newJobHost);
    }
```

This is the HTML of my Table:

```
<table id="Job-table">
<tbody>
<tr><td>Test Job</td><td>12/05/2012</td><td>Mike Smith</td></tr>
<tr><td>Test Job</td><td>12/06/2012</td><td>Mike Smith</td></tr>
<tr><td>Test Job</td><td>12/07/2012</td><td>Mike Smith</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I know there is an issue with the form input .value but I also tried to pass a static string and no luck there.

Comment: Just as a sidenote, I don't understand the benefits of the very verbose creation of textNodes. `newCellJobName.textContent = document.getElementById("JobName").value` is so much shorter.

Comment: How is anyone supposed to help you if we don't know what `insertRow` and `newRow` are/do?

Comment: @connexo I added the HTML table that insertRow and newRow are being added to. I can added the HTML form that submits the values that are added to the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple add it using inner html:

```
var inner = document.getElementById("Job-table").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("Job-table").innerHTML = inner + "<tr>...</tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a variable which isn't declared. Just change the line

```
newCellJobHost.appendChild(newJobAssigned);
```

to

```
newCellJobHost.appendChild(newJobHost);
```

Comment: Sorry that was a missed find and replace. I am using dummy names because the real ones are not appropriate to use.

Comment: Do you have a plunker? the code you wrote actually works. however, it can be optimized.